# Scala-SBT - How can I remove all 'class not found' issues in imported project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, akka

I am new to **IntelliJ IDEA**. I am importing my **Scala-SBT** project for the first time.

After import, it showing lot of `Class Not Found` problems. But in IntelliJ SBT console, clean, update, compile everything working fine. Because it is not a startup project, it is running project, lot of other people are already working.

Now, clone seperately and imported as local Scala SBT project still it not recognising my dependenty jar. Still, **Class Not Found** in all classes.

But I don't know, how to make automatically consider my dependencies from by `build.sbt`.

Also should I need to import in project settings as third party jars?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is no errors during import. If they are disable "download source" checkbox in project import settings.

You can always reimport project in IntelliJ from SBT panel

[image]

Comment: I imported as SBT project, how do I can check **import issues**. While import, it did not given any error messages.

Comment: I did not find any libraries, artifacts in Project Settings window. I think, that mean, IntelliJ Scala-sbt plugin, not fetching for libraries  anything. If it try to fetch, It should show not available message at-least.

Comment: added image, maybe it will help

Comment: For me, It not showing any projects in 'Linked SBT Projects' List. What should I do to see my project here.

Comment: It looks like, my project not imported as SBT project.  I will try to import as SBT project.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution finally,

1. I imported as Scala SBT project and i **selected build.sbt file in the root folder** instead of project root folder.
2. Downloaded exact Scala version of my project and put in project settings.
3. **Refresh Project** - It downloaded all needed jars and took 15mins to complete.

Anyway, All **class not found** errors thank God.